# Admin able to set new plaintext user password - security problem?

Tags: authentication, passwords, password-reset

I am working on this application that can be deployed and run by anyone on their server. Most often, it is run as a web service. In our new version, we removed the possibility for admins to set and view a user´s new password in account management. (The old password was never visible as there was only a salted hash of it).

The new password reset process now uses a reset link via email to the user. The reasoning from our side was that the password is supposed to be a user-only known secret so his identity can be verified as part of the authentication process. So: user receives email with reset link, sets his password, hash is stored in the database, all good. The admin never would get a glimpse of the password itself. If an admin could see the new password (like before), the password is not just knowledge of the user and would lose its value as a means of verifying identity.

Some complaints came in that this would undermine the admin role and that it would be admin´s choice if they want to provide a system that would have this strict authentication part or not. While I can partly relate to that argument, my argument is that the user himself cannot see how the system is configured but rather expects a real authentication in place. Many users don't see the potential risks of someone else knowing their password. Another complaint was the strong reliance on email (which probably could be mitigated by using other means like authenticator apps).

How do you see this?

- Is this not a standard procedure for password resets?
- Should this be a configurable part like "allow admin to set new password"?
- What do you think about allowing the admin to set at least an initial password for users that has to be changed on next login, communicating this initial password out-of-band to the user?

Comment: They need to do a risk assessment... Including the risk that a user gets their password changed, does something through the system that endangers the organization, and blames the admin, since the admin also had the user's password. If they're fine with not being able to use plausible deniability with their admins anymore, then charge them extra for developing the feature...  Call it a "corporate tier" feature.

Comment: In general, Admins should NOT know users passwords.  The risks are one of "admin leaves, has access to large amount of passwords he/she reset".  The only cases I've seen where the admin needs to know the password, the real requirement is the admin needs to be able to authenticate as the user. In a previous job I had a case where support wanted to login as another user to verify functionality.  That can be solved in a variety of different ways, but one of them shouldn't be the admin knowing the users password.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. I understand and can follow them. What do you guys think about making this configurable? In my eyes it does not achieve a security benefit as the admin is the one controlling the setting...